# Why there is only "\r" in the binding value of my multiple line TextBox?

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox, carriage-return, linefeed

I have a TextBox defined as below:

```
  <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxName" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    BorderThickness="0" 
    PlaceholderText="{Binding PlaceHolderText}"
    Text="{Binding TestValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

When I type `test1`, then type `Enter` key, and then type `test2` in this multiple lines text box, I check the value of `TestValue` and I see `test1\rtest2`. I am confused, why the return is displayed as `\r` only here. In windows isn't it be `\r\n`?

If I want to write `test1\rtest2` into xml, can I replace `\r` with `\n` which is unix style? I tried to use this but it doesn't work.

```
    XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xws.NewLineChars = "\n";
    xws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
```

Comment: is this wpf or uwp?

Comment: this is uwp on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98b368a3-89ba-4141-be15-bf4fd0335825/uwaxaml-linebreak-of-textbox-14393-vs-10586?forum=wpdevelop), it mentions this line breaks(only \r) are by design. So if you want to replace "\r" with "\n" in xml, as a workaround, you could first replace the "\r" in textbox's Text and then write it into xml.

```
string text;
if (TextBoxName.Text.Contains("\r")) { 
    text = TextBoxName.Text.Replace("\r", "\n");
}

//use text to do something.
```

Or use **Environment.NewLine** method to get the newline string defined for this environment.

```
if (TextBoxName.Text.Contains("\r"))
{
    text = TextBoxName.Text.Replace("\r", Environment.NewLine);
}
```